# sonatype/nexus3 run with --net=host, but not can success

Tags: docker, nexus

I use this script:

```
docker volume create --name nexus-data
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus --restart=always -v nexus-data:/nexus-data --net=host sonatype/nexus3
```

I can not visit 192.168.99.100:8081, so, why

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `--net=host`, you shouldn't use `-p` option, because docker ignores this option, and it's better not to use `--net=host` at all, simple expose port `-p 8081:8081`.

Do you see this message in the log (you can use `docker logs nexus`)?

> Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.14.0-04

Also, check that IP address

> 192.168.99.100

is correct.

And be aware, `--net=host` is not working on [Mac](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

Comment: thanks your answer, you are right,
 it is : Published ports are discarded when using host network mode